# Creating associated objects - Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a few simple relations in my Rails 4 application. I have three models: user, list, word.

This is for a simple 'list' application, where each user has_many words through lists.

I currently have the following associations...

#### User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
  has_many :words, through: :lists
end
```

#### List model

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :words
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### Word model

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
end
```

#### DB Scheme

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150320200247) do

# These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
enable_extension "plpgsql"

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end

create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end

create_table "words", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "word"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
  add_index "words", ["word"], name: "index_words_on_word", using: :btree
```

end

#### creating objects:

```
> user = User.create(name: "Kyle")
> list = List.create(name: "List One")
> word = Word.create(word: "StackOverflow")

# Display words in list
> list.words
```

The above association object gives an error: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column words.list_id does not exist.

I've also tried creating migrations with foreign key constraints using the Foreigner gem, but am still getting errors. Please help!

Comment: Show your schema.rb file

Comment: your are missing `list_id` in your `words` table and `user_id` in the `lists` table, these are required for the association to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what the error tells, the `list_id` column is not present,
your migration should look something like this

```
 class CreateWords < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :words do |t|
      t.string :word
      t.integer :list_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

then when creating your records:

```
> user = User.create(name: "Kyle")
> list =  List.create(name: "List One", user_id: user.id)
> word = Word.create(word: "StackOverflow", list_id: list.id)

# Should work
> list.words
```